# How to make a pop-up box in child page can't cover the mask layer in parent page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

This is my situation: `a.html` has a iframe, and the iframe's src is `b.html`.

There is a button in b.html. After press it, the parent page(a.html) will pop up a mask layer.  Meanwhile, the child page(b.html) will pop up a box. However, it turns out that the box (`z-index:2`) is covered by the mask layer in parent page(`z-index:1`). Could it be solved?

I want the box can cover the mask layer and the box must in b.html, the layer must in a.html. Waiting for your help.

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Answer (score 0):

The main code of `a.html` is below:

```
<body>
    <iframe src="b.html"></iframe>
    <div id="masklayer" style="z-index:1000;display:none;">
    </div>
</body>
```

The main code of `b.html` is below:

```
<body>
    <button onclick="showbox();">Show Box</button>
    <div id="contentbox" style="z-index:1001;display:none;">
    </div>
</body>

<script type="javasript/text">
    function showbox() {
        $("#masklayer", window.parent.document).css("display", "block");
        $("#contentbox").css("display", "block");
    }
</script>
```

PS: I just give the main css attributes.